# Perl: convert html table into picture image

Tags: html, perl, cgi

i have some coding that creates a html table. I would like to create a image file of that table (ie jpeg, gif). is there an easy way to do this?

thanks
Gordon

Answer (score 1):

On which platform? For Win32 there is [Win32::CaptureIE](http://search.cpan.org/~psme/Win32-CaptureIE-1.30/CaptureIE.pm).

This is just a synopsis from that module documentation:

```
  use Win32::CaptureIE;

  StartIE;
  Navigate('http://example.com/page.html');

  my $img = CaptureElement('tab_user_options');
  $img->Write("ie-elem.png");

  QuitIE;
```

Comment: Look at this http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.40/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Examples.pm#Example:_screenshot.pl

Comment: awesome,i will take a look at this one