# javascript code remove itself after being run

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to fill an array table by javascript code then remove that code not to allow users copy the table directly(or at least make it hard) from page as HTML.

```
<script>
   ....
</script>
```

how to remove the java script from the page after completing its mission?

thanks

Comment: I am not sure, you can remove code, while it is being executed.

Comment: Why you want to remove it? You can unbind the event/function when you don't need it..

Comment: Removing the javascript won't remove the table.

Comment: @Parse, i dont want user have access to the raw table. this code is run just once at the beginning. i dont think it will be an event. moreover, does unbinding hide the code? i'm not expert in js.

Comment: @MikeW, i dont want to remove the array. array should work. just want to remove the code.

Comment: You could theoretically remove it from the DOM but it will still be in the page source. Javascript is executed on the client side so by definition the user already has a copy of it.

Comment: Removing the code makes no sense and won't help you with preventing the user from copying the content of the table. On the other hand, if you'll place a transparent div above the table - the users won't be able to select the content using their mouse - if that's what you're aiming for.

Comment: @alfasin, its not a security issue. i'm aware that user can have access to anything on client side however i want to make it hard not impossible. a transparent div is not the case here. the table is shown in drop down list. i'm not worried about copy paste on page. i'm worried about pressing ctrl+U on firefox and hijacking table from there.

Comment: Even if you remove HTML from CTRL+U page, user will just press F12 and copy table from Firebug/Developer Tools.

Comment: Indeed... google chrome, right click -> inspect element -> DEL key : The overlay is gone and you can select what you want

Comment: maybe i should look for encoded js, does this way effect?

Comment: You could make it another way around---don't have the JavaScript in the HTML at all but use AJAX to retrieve it from the server or `document.write()` to insert it to the page dynamically. It still won't prevent people from seeing it, but if, for example, 10 people out of 100 know about the "view source" feature, maybe only 8 people out of 100 know about the browser tools.

Comment: yes, maybe. but i can not give opinion about it at right now. first i have to learn Ajax!

Comment: Then learn Ajax, removing JS-code much more difficult then AJAX...

Comment: Another option is to turn your table into an image, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13904625/1057429

Comment: @alfasin, this is a table in concept not an html table. it is shown in a drop down menu.

Comment: If your array data really is confidential, you shouldn't have it on the client side. Consider creating the desired content on the server and just deliver the output.

Comment: @Robert, no it is issue of author rights not issue of confidentiality.

Comment: @gerrnar I'm poinmting out that there are tools that enable you to turn a text dynamically into an image. prople can't copy text from an image

Comment: @alfasin, so i cannot use image drop down. unless breaking down them into a lot of images! 200 of images as choices.

Comment: @gerrnar even if it was 1000 options, when you do something programmatically it doesn't take more effort.

Comment: true. and thanks for your solution. it is possible. however i dont have enough js knowledge to implement and support it(dynamic theme).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see a point in removing the JavaScript, but it would be possible. Give the script-element an ID to make it easier to select. Then place the code that will handle the removal in a separate script-element.

Given that the code you wan't to remove isn't asynchronous, something like this would do it:

```
<script id="foo">
    // Do your stuff here, create the table or whatever necessary
</script>

<script>
(function () {
    var node = document.getElementById("foo");
    if (node.parentNode) {
      node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    }
})();
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRLGy/)

**Update:**

As Juhana points out in the comments, this will remove the script-element from the DOM, but the script element will still be visible if you look at the actual source of the page.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, this "works" but has practically zero effect. The JavaScript has already ran, and the browser's "view source" shows the *original* HTML, not the current DOM.

Comment: thank you so much. it was what i was looking for. it works against firebug. but still shown by ctrl+U. now i'm doubtful whether what i'm looking for is theoretically possible or not.

Comment: running by firefox 21.0 on Ubuntu Os and in localhost, it showed the foo area to me.

Comment: better to be combined with solution of 'Anderson'. unfortunately my edit to this answer did not get moderator approval.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove script element or do anything else but user can still get the table through debug mode. There are some ways to encrypt your source code，try: http://jsobfuscate.com/

Answer (score 0):

May be you can **make it hard** by disabling copy and paste function in your webpage:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function killCopy(e){
return false
}
function reEnable(){
return true
}
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
if (window.sidebar){
document.onmousedown=killCopy
document.onclick=reEnable
}
</script>
```

see http://www.boogiejack.com/no_copy_paste.html

But still users can get it, because they already have a copy of html on their local machine

Comment: thank, but the discussion here is about hijacking code from source not from the page.(i was not who give downvote)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.currentScript.remove()
```